# Is this a casting bug in SQL Server 2016 RC0?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Returns `45.2478`

```
SELECT
    CAST(
        geography::STPointFromText( 'POINT(-81.2545 44.1244)', 4326 ).Lat + 1.12342342
        AS VARCHAR(50)
    )
```

Returns `4.524782342440000e+001`

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(
        VARCHAR(50),
        geography::STPointFromText( 'POINT(-81.2545 44.1244)' , 4326 ).Lat + 1.1234234244,
        2
    )
```

According to the "Truncating and Rounding Results" section on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) it looks like CAST should never truncate a float but it's doing it in this case.

Comment: Your examples are using literals of type `decimal` not `float`.

Comment: @MartinSmith thank you very much, this was driving me crazy, I removed the literal decimal examples, it's just floats now. Assuming float+decimal = float

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to the docs that you included in the question has an answer.

`CAST` is the same as `CONVERT` without explicitly specifying the optional style parameter.

> float and real Styles
>
> ```
> Value:  0 (default)
> Output: A maximum of 6 digits. Use in scientific notation, when appropriate.
> ```

So, when you use `CAST` it is the same as using `CONVERT` with `style=0`. Which returns a maximum of 6 digits, i.e. result is rounded to 6 digits.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the `style` part you mentioned in `CONVERT` function

Your query with `style = 2`

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),geography::STPointFromText('POINT(-81.2545 44.1244)',4326).Lat+1.1234234244,2)
```

**Result :** `4.524782342440000e+001`

But when I remove the `Style` part from `Convert` function

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),geography::STPointFromText('POINT(-81.2545 44.1244)',4326).Lat+1.1234234244)
```

**Result :** `45.2478`

which is same as `CAST` function

**FYI,** Style `2` is used to format dates in `yy.mm.dd` format

Answer (score 0):

Quote from you: *"it looks like CAST should never truncate a float but it's doing it in this case."*

Attention: The example you write here does not use `float`, but `decimal`. These are two different types, and it is very important to distinguish between them. `decimal`has by default 6 digits, that explains this behaviour.

Everything is in check. SQL Server is one of Microsoft's most stable software pieces, you will hardly find a bug there ;)

Comment: I remove any decimals from the example, should be all float now, assuming float+decimal=float.  Also I'm on a RC0 version of SQL server, I've already encountered known bugs, it's prerelease software.